# How Upload 2 file using backbone and rest api

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, rest, backbone.js

How to upload files using backbone and rest api (codeignitier). following is my html form data:-

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="upgrade_firmware" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <div class="control-group">
               <label class="control-label muted">IMG</label>
               <div class="controls">
                   <input type="file" id="fu-img" value="" name="fu-img" >
               </div>
           </div> 
           <div class="control-group">
               <label class="control-label muted">MD5</label>
               <div class="controls">
                   <input type="file" id="fu-md5" value="" name="fu-md5">
               </div>
           </div>   
</form>
```

How can i upload this in my view files. if it is a form to create or delete i can use model.save in backbone and pass that in to rest api.But in this case this is a upload so how can i do it with backbone and rest api.

1. if i click upload button i can upload it to /home/upload directory and it should be a get call , why because i need to check the file is already there or not..if i call get i will get backend response as {"file":true} ,it means file already there so i exit.
2. if get call success i redirect to progress page,{"progress": 40%}

Is it possible to upload like this? upload file using get call and take appropriate response from backend? using backbone and rest api.

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require(APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class FRM_Upload extends REST_Controller
{   

    function api_get()
    {

        //upload to /home/upload dir
       $message = json_decode(file_get_contents("assets/json/firmware_progress.json"));
        $this->response($message, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: you will have to set enctype to `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to upload your file(s)

Comment: thats fine. but is thre any way to do it in backbone.js

Comment: i have no experience of backbone but sine its a javascript library all i can tell you is since javascript cant read the contents of the client side file you cannot upload the file using it (xhr2 can). you will have to use a plugin which uses flash or you can use iframes for creating an illusion if upload files with ajax